Delphi drag/drop ultra 4K touch screen
I've created a simple drag/drop application in Delphi (10.3.3), with 9 TListBox components on it, and a few items which can be dragged/dropped between the listboxes.
On an Ultra 4K touch monitor, the items can be dragged and dropped with the mouse, however when it's done with touch, we get an Invalid floating point operation.
I already tried to change de DPI awareness in the manifest, currently it's set to "Per Monitor v2", other options doesn't seem to help.
I'm using plain Delphi drag/drop, so I'm sure it's not a third party component.
Source code of the form, events are linked to all listboxes:
procedure TForm1.ListBoxDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Source is TListBox then
  begin
    if TListBox(Source).ItemIndex <> -1 then
    begin
      // Add item to new listbox
      TListBox(Sender).Items.Add(TListBox(Source).Items[TListBox(Source).ItemIndex]);
      // Remove from old one
      TListBox(Source).Items.Delete(TListBox(Source).ItemIndex);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBoxDragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  if Source is TListBox then
   Accept := True
 else
   Accept := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBoxMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);

begin
   if Button = mbLeft then  { drag only if left button pressed }
   begin
     with Sender as TListBox do  { treat Sender as TFileListBox }
       begin
         if ItemAtPos(Point(X, Y), True) >= 0 then  { is there an item here? }
           BeginDrag(False);  { if so, drag it }
     end;
   end;
end;


On which line in your source do you get this error? Do you use plain old Delphi Drag'n'Drop or are you using a 3rd party component to implement it (if so, which one)? Show the code for the DragBegin event (if the error occurs when the drag is started) the DragOver event (if the error occurs when the item is dragged into the target) or the DragEnd event (if the error occurs when the item is dropped). I'm not 100% sure what the actual names are of the events (it might also depend on the library used), but you can probably figure out what I mean from the description I gave.

@HeartWare Please see my edit.
Exception is thrown somewhere inside VLC unit itself

At what point is the error displayed? Try setting a breakpoint on the appropriate event handler in your code to see if it occurs before or after that event has run.

@HeartWare Can't debug it right here, as I don't have the monitor at my location. The error is before entering the 'Drop' event (it doesn't enter this event after the error), so it's during the dragging

Is it before or after you "DragOver" a listbox? It could also be the DragOver event... Is it only after you "release" the drop?

Haven't checked with a breakpoint in the DragOver event, as it would be triggered breaking your drag/drop event.. (As it would focus the Delphi IDE). It is during the drag, so we didn't released yet

Before or after you leave the listbox where you started the drag operation? What were you dragging over when the exception happened?

After we leave the listbox, if we are approx at 75% of the screen (dragging from left to right). Dragging over a listbox. Not at the start of one, but in the middle. Looks like if we have a too high resolution, this overflow exists

Try to confirm this by moving the form left and see if that pushes the (relative) position where the error occurs to the right. If so, try to (guesstimate) the X-coordinate where the error occurs (if it's a 2160xYYYY screen, and the problem occurs at around 3/4 to the right, then the X-coordinate is 2160/4*3). Also try to lower the (pixel) resolution on the screen to see if that has any impact on the error and/or the location of where the error occurs.

I don't understand what you are saying in the first part. We have the form open full screen, all listboxes at the same size filling the screen.
I already tried to lower the resolution, for example to 1920x1080, it all goes well. It's ultra 4k, so 3840px width. If it's goes wrong at 75%, thats about 2880.
I remember I tried at a resolution in between also, i think it was something about 3200width. This also gave an error, but at a later point.
Whats weird is that it's only giving an error on touch, not on mouse drag/drop.

Stacktrace points to Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DefaultHandler (Line 10319, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 30)
